# CakePHP default route parameter

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have a problem with routing in CakePHP. I want to pass parameter to route, but this parameter need to have default value.
My route:

```
$routes->connect('/exchangeOffer/add/:type', ['controller' => 'Offer', 'action' => 'add'], ['pass' => ['type'], 'type' => '(NORMAL|AUTO)']);
```

This route works onnly when I go to one of addresses:

> http://domain/exchangeOffer/add/NORMAL
>
> http://domain/exchangeOffer/add/AUTO

But I want it to work with address

> http://domain/exchangeOffer/add

And then pass default type parameter as NORMAL.
I know that something like this is posible in Zend Framework, but I'm totally new in CakePHP, and can't find a way to do this(looked through many post and answers, not only here, but none of them helped).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve this at routing level, then you'll have to add an additional route with no `:type` route element set, and a default `type` param passed in the defaults array, like

```
$routes->connect(
    '/exchangeOffer/add/:type',
    [
        'controller' => 'Offer',
        'action' => 'add'
    ],
    [
        'pass' => ['type'],
        'type' => '(NORMAL|AUTO)'
    ]
);

$routes->connect(
    '/exchangeOffer/add',
    [
        'controller' => 'Offer',
        'action' => 'add',
        'type' => 'NORMAL'
    ],
    [
        'pass' => ['type']
    ]
);
```

And if you want to be able to generate URLs (for example via `Router::url()`) without defining a type, you'll have to add (append - as order matters) a third rule with no type being involved at all

```
$routes->connect(
    '/exchangeOffer/add',
    [
        'controller' => 'Offer',
        'action' => 'add'
    ]
);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Connecting Routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#routes-configuration)**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to the action,you just input Controller, cakephp will select the default action in controller ( it will be index )
example:

```
Router::connect(
    '/add/*', array('controller' => 'users','action' => 'index' )
);
```

when ever you go go http://domain.com/add/some-thing.html or http://domain.com/add, system will call the controller USERS and action INDEX

Hope it help you